# Less try-catch statements?

Tags: c#, windows, optimization, registry, try-catch

I'm a bit frustrating trying to figure out what the best route is to handle exceptions in C# with a try-catch statement. I want to have the code so if an exception is thrown trying to open a Registry key then it will move on to the next Registry key. The only way I can think of to do is this by encapsulating each of the function calls in a try-catch statement but to me it seems long way to do that.

- Is there any other way to do this?
- Can you have all the code in a single try-catch statement and when an exception occurs, have it move to the next line of code (like step over)?
- I know this is probably a no, but can the `ScanSubKey` function be used to check for exceptions if the variable is set in a parameter?

**Without try-catch statements**

```
ScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot);
ScanSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"));
ScanSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"));
if (Is64BitOS)
{
    ScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Wow6432Node"));
    ScanSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node"));
    ScanSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node"));
}
```

**Example**

```
try {
    ScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot);
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
}
try {
    ScanSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"));
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
}
try {
    ScanSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"));
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
}

if (Is64BitOS)
{
    try {
        ScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Wow6432Node"));
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
    }
    try {
        ScanSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node"));
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
    }
    try {
        ScanSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node"));
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2294d2ce-e6ae-4152-b022-61aa2ae9372d/trycatchcontinue-with-next-line-in-try-block?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call this an "Executor":

```
    public static void Execute(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

and then use it:

```
Execute(() => ScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot));
```

Comment: @Maarten I won't argue that this is good practice - but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 2):

Create a new method `TryScanSubKey`. Then your code looks clean again:

```
TryScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot);
TryScanSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"));
TryScanSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE"));
if (Is64BitOS)
{
    TryScanSubKey(Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Wow6432Node"));
    TryScanSubKey(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node"));
    TryScanSubKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node"));
}
```

The implementation of `TryScanSubKey` should be obvious, but, for completeness, here it is:

```
void TryScanSubKey(RegistryKey key)
{
    try
    {
        ScanSubKey(key);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Note that, *in general*, swallowing an error is bad practice, and swallowing *all* errors is worse still. So please consider (at least) replacing `catch (Exception ex)` with something more specific, e.g. `catch (TheSpecificExceptionThrownByScanSubKey ex)`.

Comment: Wouldn't this still cause the program to fail if an exception is thrown because if the registry key cannot be opened before it is sent to ``TryScanSubKey`` then there's nothing to catch it?

Comment: @ub3rst4r: [RegistryKey.OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z9f66s0a(v=vs.110).aspx) won't throw an exception if the key is missing -- it just returns null, which can easily be checked in TryScanSubKey. If the operation fails for some other reason, the program *should* fail, because in that case something in the registry is terribly broken.

Comment: What if it's due to with permissions for the sub key?

Comment: @ub3rst4r: Then a SecurityException is thrown. I would argue that this is a good thing, since a normal user *should* have read access to HKCU, HKLM\Software and HKCU\Software (and the WOW64 counterparts). If access is denied, something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be a slightly better approach:

```
public bool TryOpenRegKey(RegistryKey regKey, string subKey = default(string))
{
  try
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subKey))
      ScanSubKey(regKey);
    else
      ScanSubKey(regKey.OpenSubKey(subKey));

    return true;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("The following error occurred opening a registry key: " + ex.Message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
TryOpenRegKey(Registry.ClassesRoot);
TryOpenRegKey(Registry.LocalMachine, "SOFTWARE");
TryOpenRegKey(Registry.CurrentUser, "SOFTWARE");

if (Is64BitOS)
{
  TryOpenRegKey(Registry.ClassesRoot, "Wow6432Node");
  TryOpenRegKey(Registry.LocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node");
  TryOpenRegKey(Registry.CurrentUser, "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered placing a try/catch inside of the ScanSubKey function itself and return if an error occurs?